# How to drive a speaker with amplifier using 3.5 mm jack

Tags: schematics, speakers

I have two bare loudspeakers salvaged from old speakers and I would like to control them from computer using 3.5 mm jack. The speakers had a control board, but that is broken. I would like to drive 5 W 4 Ω loudspeakers. When posting schematic please add legend to describe what each symbol does. For amplifier circuit would be controlled by potentiometer. And preferably mono for two speakers.

I found TDA1905 IC to connect the speaker to which works perfectly since it outputs 5 W 4 Ω which is perfect, but my question about application circuit in the manual is what are V<sub>I</sub>, V<sub>T</sub>, C<sub>5</sub>, V<sub>S</sub> and these symbols that I highlighted in red in picture below.

> [image: Application circuit]

Another question is: Can I put speakers in parallel as shown in schematic above, i.e. two identical speakers?

**Edit 2**: V<sub>T</sub> seems to be threshold, but what kind of voltages are accepted?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your questions suggest to me that you should start with much simpler circuits before trying to build this amplifier yourself. It sounds like you don't have much experience with reading schematics and building circuits, and it would be a shame if your first attempt was overly frustrating. Furthermore, the TDA1905 is an obsolete device.

Comment: I'm very weird person. My first circuit was ac to dc rectifier. 9V 1A. If TDA 1905 is obsolete what device does the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, we don't recommend specific parts on this site. Part of your learning experience could be to become a **parts search** ninja...try digging around at Digikey or Mouser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The symbols circled in red are the ground connections
- V<sub>I</sub> is the input voltage
- V<sub>S</sub>  is the supply voltage
- V<sub>T</sub>  is the threshold voltage for the mute capability. From the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000121.pdf), V<sub>T</sub>needs to be between 1.9 and 4.7 V to turn muting off.
- C<sub>5</sub>  is the 0.1 µF capacitor
- Two 8 Ω speakers in parallel would equal the 4 Ω load shown

You could use this schematic, from the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000121.pdf), which does not have the muting capability:

> [image: Non-muting circuit]

As Elliot points out in [their comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443283/how-to-drive-a-speaker-with-amplifier-using-3-5mm-jack/443302#comment1109972_443283), the manufacturer has marked the TDA1905 as obsolete.

Comment: What would be better way to use 2 speakers at once? 2 seperate, 2 series? in parallel it would reduce it to 2Ω. In series it would increase to 8Ω. 2 seperate however is more expensive.

Comment: 2x4Ω in series = 8Ω; 2x4Ω in parallel = 2Ω. So to have a load equal to 4Ω as shown in the schematic, you would want 2x8Ω speakers in parallel. What do you mean by `separate`? You asked `Can I put speakers in parallel` - the answer is yes. You also ask `Can I put speakers in parallel as shown in schematic above` but there aren't any parallel speakers shown in the schematic.

Comment: I'm worried if something would break if have TDA 1905 5W 4Ω's and put my speakers in parallel, also another problem is my speakers are 4Ω not 8Ω ones.

Comment: If you have two 4Ω speakers, then you could make two circuits to connect each one of them to, in order to have a stereo output. BTW, please don't forget to upvote.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I don't have enough reputation to give you a upvote, but I would.